# debugging shaders on Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm experimenting with using programmable shaders for materials in Gazebo.  GLSL type shaders seem to work well, but I find that a programming error will only result in a white object with no corresponding error logged to standard output.  Is there any way for me to locate coding errors in shader programs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11238/debugging-shaders-on-gazebo/) by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 586 on 2011-09-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-11-05**:
The best solution I have found so far is to use a separate shader designer program to validate the programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update a year later - the ogre.log file in the hidden .gazebo directory includes the compilation errors for the shaders.

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2012-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0